# OpenNMS unable to collect jmx mbeans java.util.map/set data

Tags: monitoring, jmx, jconsole, mbeans, opennms

I am trying to collect JMX MBean data from OpenNMS to monitor. But unable to retrieve java.util.map / java.util.set data using OpenNMS. Using Jconsole have verified that the data is getting monitored, but there are some configuration issues in OpenNMS. I am able to collect and monitor string and integer values in OpenNMS but not for set or map.

Two question I need to ask:
1. Can we collect MBean data for java.util.map/ java.util.set in OpenNMS?
2. What is the configuration for the data type in jmx-datacollection.xml for set and map type of collection?